# Putting Widget above a ListView in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

The below code is working fine with me for calling and displaying data from firestore:

```
return ListView(
 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
 children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
);
```

But If I tried to put it in a column so I add another widget above it, it fails and give `stack overflow`:

```
return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
    Text('Hellow'),
  ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
  children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
)]);
```

Comment: Also In your `ListView` add - `shrinkWrap: true,`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to put your `ListView` inside an `Expanded` widget so it knows how much space it can fill.

```
return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Hellow'),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          children:
              snapshot.map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: Right answer. If you want the text to be scrollable also, then you have to wrap your column in CustomScrollView and use Sliverlist.