# Putting Container with Text above List View in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to place a simple Container with some text above a ListView in Flutter.
I tried to place the text in the AppBar but I found out the AppBar is not intended to do so.

It should look something like this (except the description should be outsourced to a dedicated container).
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEpdG.png)

I tried following [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887504/putting-widget-above-a-listview-in-flutter) but wasn't able to accomplish anything.

```html
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: [
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
          Category(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

I am new to Flutter and new to stackoverflow so I hope this question is fine.
Thanks in advance and kind regards :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, wrap your ListView with Expanded then wrap it with Column.
Here is some code examples:

```
return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          const Text("HEADER"),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 30,
                      width: 50,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Container could be Scaffold's body. It is up to you.

Comment: You can remove the container here.

Answer (score 0):

- Wrap the Container with Column.
- Add the Container with Text in the Column.
- Wrap the ListView's Container with Expanded so it takes up the space that's left in screen.
- Enable shrinkWrap in the ListView.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      const FlutterLogo(), //replace it with your container with text
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 0),
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true, //make sure to enable shrink wrap
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: [
              ...
```